# GoogleSignin.signIn() does not prompt the modal but crashes the app every time

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, google-signin

Im trying to use GoogleSignin in my app and have followed these docs https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/blob/master/README.md.
I have done all the setup for this and I have created eas build for my app and everything. But when I press button that should start function which includes Googlesignin.signIn() that should prompt the modal for user to sign in with google, the app crashes and doesn't give any errors? It just shuts down. Is there something that could come up to mind what can cause this kind of behavior, I handle all the errors like docs instruct to do, but no error occurs, the app just shuts down. I'm using react native expo and IOS Simulator